# Kill process started with NPM (pm2)

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I installed pm2 with NPM without the global flag. Then I started the app  with "npm start" that declared on `package.json` as

```
"start": "pm2 start index.js"
```

How can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access locally-installed `pm2` with `npx`:

```
$ npx pm2 list
$ npx pm2 stop 0 # first app will have ID=0
```

But in general, I would manage it by attaching a name to the app. Let's edit your `package.json`:

```
"start": "pm2 start index.js --name my-app"
"stop": "pm2 stop my-app",
"logs": "pm2 logs my-app"
```

And then:

```
$ npm run start
$ npm run logs
$ npm run stop
```

Comment: Thanks! that make a lot of sense ha. I didn't put a --name to the start, so I guess it will need to be killed with "0"

Answer (score 0):

Oh, was easy as installing it globally

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

and then kill the process. I thought it will be a "different" thing